# Order two unequal list issue

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

How can we sort two list of unequal size and where pojo class Field does not implement equals/hashcode method.I am unable to sort the list based on list1 order.I want the order in list to be occured has "t" and then "s".Is it possible to achieve this scenario?

```
Field f=new Field();
f.setKey("s");
f.setValue("he");

Field f1=new Field();
f1.setKey("t");
f1.setValue("she");

List<Field> list = new ArrayList<Field>();
list.add(f);
list.add(f1);

Field f2=new Field();
f2.setKey("t");
f2.setValue("he");

Field f3=new Field();
f3.setKey("s");
f3.setValue("she");

Field f4=new Field();
f4.setKey("u");
f4.setValue("she");

List<Field> list1 = new ArrayList<Field>();
list1.add(f2);
list1.add(f3);
list1.add(f4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Field>() { /* ... */ });`

see [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: I have tried using    final Map<FP, Integer> indices = new HashMap<FP, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            indices.put(list.get(i), i);
        }
        Collections.sort(list1, new Comparator<FP>() {
            public int compare(FP o1, FP o2) {
                int index1 = (Integer) (indices.containsKey(o1) ? indices
                        .get(o1) : +1);
                int index2 = (Integer) (indices.containsKey(o2) ? indices
                        .get(o2) : +1);
                return index1 - index2;
            }

        });
not working

Comment: can you please check this out

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in methods to achieve what you want, but you can easily do this with `Collections.sort` by providing your own comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Field>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Field f1, Field f2) {
        // compare your fields here and
        //     return -1 if f2 should be before f2
        //     return 0 if they are the same
        //     return 1 if f1 should be after f2

        return ...;
    }
});
```

Comment: final Map<FP, Integer> indices = new HashMap<FP, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            indices.put(list.get(i), i);
        }
        Collections.sort(list1, new Comparator<FP>() {
            public int compare(FP o1, FP o2) {
                int index1 = (Integer) (indices.containsKey(o1) ? indices
                        .get(o1) : +1);
                int index2 = (Integer) (indices.containsKey(o2) ? indices
                        .get(o2) : +1);
                return index1 - index2;
            }

        });
not working for me FP is a Field

Comment: @pars Why are you using hashmaps?  I thought you are dealing with lists?  Also note that hashmap is not sorted.  If you need them sorted, then you must use SortedMap.

Comment: ya i am dealing with list,how can i modify the above code to sort,its not working

Comment: @pars But where are Maps coming from?  Your `compare` method seems wrong.  Lay out your comparison rules and make sure that method addresses all of them.

Comment: I am adding the list in a map before comparing ,i am not getting this can you please edit and show me

Comment: ,please provide your snippet for the above list,my code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try out something like this :

```
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.Map.Entry; 
public class HashMapComparison 
{     
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {        
 HashMap<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();   
 map1.put("s", "he");     
 map1.put("t", "she");    
 HashMap<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();  
 map2.put("t", "he");     
 map2.put("s", "she");  
 map2.put("u", "she"); 
 HashMap<Integer, String> orderedMap1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();  
 for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : map2.entrySet()) {      
 Integer key = entry.getKey();        
 for(Entry<Integer, String> entry : map1.entrySet()){
 if(key.equals(entry.getKey()){
   orderedMap1.put(entry);
 }
 }
 }     
 }
```

Comment: can u please explain the same for list